# Meanings of 千里 and 西千里

Tags: words, proper-nouns

> あそこだったら、地下鉄で行くといいよ。**千里**で乗り換えて、**西千里**で降りればいいんじゃない。

For context, the person here is answering a question where someone asks how to get to 芸術センター.

Are 千里 and 西千里 proper nouns naming the stations, or is http://jisho.org/word/%E5%8D%83%E9%87%8C meant here? 西千里 seems to be a composition of 西 and 千里, but I can't make sense of it.
And just to make sure that I got the basic meaning of the sentence right, in the second sentence the speaker basically says that it should be okay if it is required to change trains once before arriving at the destination/ultimately exiting the subway?

Answer (score 3):

In Osaka there are several stations having [千里]{せんり} in their names. For instance [北千里駅{きたせんりえき}](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%97%E5%8D%83%E9%87%8C%E9%A7%85), [南千里駅{みなみせんりえき}](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%97%E5%8D%83%E9%87%8C%E9%A7%85).

What I understand from the second sentence is that the speaker thinks that [西千里]{にしせんり} station is the nearest station from the destination (あそこ) and that to get to 西千里 it is simplest to change trains at [千里]{せんり}.

Answer (score 0):

千里｛ちさと｝is in this case the name of station and is thus different to the unit of measurement 千里｛せんり｝ (one thousand ri). See here: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%83%E9%87%8C%E9%A7%85_%28%E6%9B%96%E6%98%A7%E3%81%95%E5%9B%9E%E9%81%BF%29

Comment: the problem is that according to the furigana of my textbook, the kanji indeed reads せんりhere...^^

Comment: There are names where it is pronounced せんり as well. Just from reading the text I couldn't know which was the case here. On another note, if you don't like my answer, that is up to you, but you could at least comment on what you think is wrong.

Comment: @Yuuichi, we know nothing about the context, it might very well be a fictive conversation. It is however obvious that it refers to station names, and it is also very common to add a cardinal direction as a prefix in Japanese place names.

Comment: When I checked them on internet, there isn't 千里(せんり) station but 千里(ちさと) station. And there isn't 西千里 station. The writer of the textbook might be confused. Yes, they are the station's name.

Comment: I edited in some more information.